# Why did Beaver say, "There's trim there"?

Tags: dreamcatcher

In the first half of the movie, Beaver says to Pete that he met a girl at Bingo and made love to her:

> Pete: Bingo? Did you say bingo, like the game in church basements?
>
> Beaver: **There's trim there**.
>
> Pete: Beaver!

Comment: I guess your question is about the movie "[Dreamcatcher](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285531)", but maybe it's appropriate to mention that in the body of the question, rather than just in a tag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this instance, he's using the term *trim* in its slightly less crude manner, to denote the fact that there are (sexually) available women there:

> [**noun.**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trimmer) A woman, esp one regarded as an object of sexual conquest (Circa 1955+)

[Dictionary Central](http://www.dictionarycentral.com/definition/trim.html) also has this to offer

> **noun**: A female, especially an attractive girl. A briefly fashionable phrase used in hip circles and among medical students,
>   etc. in the early 1990s. It was probably adapted from the (somewhat
>   dated) black American use of the word to denote the female genitals...

---

### For the record, using this term in mixed company is likely to earn you a slap.

Answer (score 15):

Trim is rude slang for female genitalia. The phrase in this context means that it was legitimate reasoning to meet a woman at bingo as there are women physically there.

Comment: I feel like this answer is more in the spirit of the original usage than the accepted one. +1 to both

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks

Comment: Reminiscent, alas, of a line in *Dogma*, ...